# image button background shape

Tags: android, imagebutton

I've assigned an oval shape xml to my image button. when I set src of image button and then set the scale type to "center" every thing is good and my rectangular frame image is placed completely inside the circle. but when I when I change the image source programmatically with a click on image button, then the circular background is removed and result is a rectangular frame image button. I want circular frame of image button always be constant and every change be happened inside the circular frame.
my shape xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <stroke android:color="#ff818181"
            android:width="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

my changing image source code as button clicked:

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.example);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want circular frame of image button always be constant and every change be happened inside the circular frame

You need to write own custom view for that: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,It works for me

```
imageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.example));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your button to an image `onClick()` try to make another drawable with the same code for circular button and change the background their and `setBackground()` for your button.

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customBtn);
```